# Как в массиве вызвать определенное значение и сопоставить с другим javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть три чекбокса, как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на второй чекбокс, картинка появлялась та, которая тоже 2 по очереди

```js
const modalInput = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-options-box__item input');
            const modalCheck = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-options-box__item label i');
        
            $(document).ready(function() {
                console.log(modalInput);
                [].forEach.call(modalInput,function(el){
                    el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                        console.log(modalCheck);
                        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                            modalCheck.style.display = 'block';
                        } else {
                            modalCheck.style.display= 'none';
                        }
                    });
                });
                
            });
```

```css
.modal-options
    width: 100%
    height: 100vh
    background: #2D313A
    &-grid
        padding-top: 100px
        background: #222529
        display: grid
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr
        height: 800px
    &-box
        padding-left: 40px
        margin-top: 50px
        display: flex
        flex-direction: column
        &__item
            margin-top: 14px
            display: flex
            justify-content: flex-start
            
        &__text
            color: #A2ABBA
            font-size: 18px
            font-family: 'Exo2-SemiBold'
            line-height: 30px
            margin-left: 20px
        &__title
            color: #A2ABBA
            font-size: 22px
            font-family: 'ProximaNova-Regular'
            line-height: 30px
        &__item
            i
                font-size: 20px
                color: #A2ABBA
                line-height: 30px
                margin-left: 20px
                display: none
            label
                position: relative
                display: inline-block
                width: 36px
                height: 36px
                background: #292D36
                transition: 400ms 100ms ease-out
                &:hover
                    border-color: #FF686B
                .checked
                    position: absolute
                    left: 50%
                    top: 50%
                    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
                    margin-left: 0
                    line-height: 20px
            input[type="checkbox"]
                position: absolute
                left: -1px
```

```html
<div class="modal-options-grid__item">
                    <div class="modal-options-box">
                        <div class="modal-options-box__item">
                            <div class="modal-options-box__title">
                                1
                            </div>
                            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-options-box__item">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="cb1">
                            <label for="cb1"><i class="fas fa-check checked"></i></label>
                            <div class="modal-options-box__text">
                                Да
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-options-box">
                        <div class="modal-options-box__item">
                            <div class="modal-options-box__title">
                                2
                            </div>
                            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-options-box__item">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="cb2">
                            <label for="cb1"><i class="fas fa-check checked"></i></label>
                            <div class="modal-options-box__text">
                                Да
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-options-box">
                        <div class="modal-options-box__item">
                            <div class="modal-options-box__title">
                                3
                            </div>
                            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-options-box__item">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" >
                            <label for="cb1"><i class="fas fa-check checked"></i></label>
                            <div class="modal-options-box__text">
                                Да
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.modal-options-box__item input').change(function(){
  var $i = $(this).closest('.modal-options-box__item').find("i");
  $i.toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
}).change();
```

```css
.modal-options
    width: 100%
    height: 100vh
    background: #2D313A
    &-grid
        padding-top: 100px
        background: #222529
        display: grid
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr
        height: 800px
    &-box
        padding-left: 40px
        margin-top: 50px
        display: flex
        flex-direction: column
        &__item
            margin-top: 14px
            display: flex
            justify-content: flex-start
            
        &__text
            color: #A2ABBA
            font-size: 18px
            font-family: 'Exo2-SemiBold'
            line-height: 30px
            margin-left: 20px
        &__title
            color: #A2ABBA
            font-size: 22px
            font-family: 'ProximaNova-Regular'
            line-height: 30px
        &__item
            i
                font-size: 20px
                color: #A2ABBA
                line-height: 30px
                margin-left: 20px
                display: none
            label
                position: relative
                display: inline-block
                width: 36px
                height: 36px
                background: #292D36
                transition: 400ms 100ms ease-out
                &:hover
                    border-color: #FF686B
                .checked
                    position: absolute
                    left: 50%
                    top: 50%
                    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
                    margin-left: 0
                    line-height: 20px
            input[type="checkbox"]
                position: absolute
                left: -1px
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-options-grid__item">
                    <div class="modal-options-box">
                        <div class="modal-options-box__item">
                            <div class="modal-options-box__title">
                                1
                            </div>
                            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-options-box__item">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="cb1">
                            <label for="cb1"><i class="fas fa-check checked">fas</i></label>
                            <div class="modal-options-box__text">
                                Да
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-options-box">
                        <div class="modal-options-box__item">
                            <div class="modal-options-box__title">
                                2
                            </div>
                            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-options-box__item">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="cb2">
                            <label for="cb1"><i class="fas fa-check checked">fas</i></label>
                            <div class="modal-options-box__text">
                                Да
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-options-box">
                        <div class="modal-options-box__item">
                            <div class="modal-options-box__title">
                                3
                            </div>
                            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-options-box__item">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" >
                            <label for="cb1"><i class="fas fa-check checked">fas</i></label>
                            <div class="modal-options-box__text">
                                Да
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: проблема в том, что при нажатии на 2 чекбокс, срабатывает все равно первый

Comment: @yavis В коде ответа?

Comment: все работает, поправил, спасибо огромное)